# Combine two plots into one with different colored legends

Tags: plotting

After much help from this community, I finally have a way to plot the real solutions to the determinant. However, this may seem like a stupid request, I want to combine both figures that result from this code into one with a legend for each w.

```
k = 9.; l = 12.; m = 2.; M = 4.;
mat = {{m*w^2 - 2*k, k, k*zeta}, {k, M*w^2 - (l + k), 
l}, {-k*zeta, l, M*w^2 - (k - l)}};
mydet = ExpToTrig[Det[mat]];
sol = Solve[mydet == 0, w];
funcs = Chop[w /. sol /. {zeta -> Exp[-3I ka]} // FullSimplify];
Show[Table[Plot[Max[0, (funcs[[k]] + Conjugate[funcs[[k]]])/2], {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Black], {k, 1, Length[funcs]}], PlotRange -> All]
Show[Table[Plot[Max[0, (funcs[[k]] - Conjugate[funcs[[k]]])/(2 I)], {ka, 
 0, \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> Blue], {k, 1, Length[funcs]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

I hope someone can answer this so I can finally be done with this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re = Plot[
  Evaluate[Max[0, (funcs[[#]] + Conjugate[funcs[[#]]])/2] & /@ 
    Range[Length[funcs]]], {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> (ColorData[3] /@ Range[Length[funcs]]), 
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{"Re\[ThinSpace]", 
        HoldForm@Subscript[w, #]}] & /@ Range[Length[funcs]])]
```

[image]

```
im = Plot[
  Evaluate[Max[0, (funcs[[#]] - Conjugate[funcs[[#]]])/(2 I)] & /@ 
    Range[Length[funcs]]], {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thread[{Dashed, ColorData[3] /@ Range[Length[funcs]]}],
   PlotLegends -> (Row[{"Im\[ThinSpace]", 
        HoldForm@Subscript[w, #]}] & /@ Range[Length[funcs]])]
```

[image]

You can combine both, but it looks not so good for me:

```
Show[re, im]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To answer question in comment about plotting derivatives:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Evaluate[UnitStep[Re@funcs[[#]]] Re@D[funcs[[#]], ka]/ka &] /@ 
   Range[Length[funcs]]], {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[3] /@ Range[Length[funcs]]), Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> (Row[{"Re'\[ThinSpace]", 
       HoldForm@Subscript[w, #]}] & /@ Range[Length[funcs]])]
```

[image]

and for imaginary part:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Evaluate[UnitStep[Im@funcs[[#]]] Im@D[funcs[[#]], ka]/ka &] /@ 
   Range[Length[funcs]]], {ka, 0, \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[3] /@ Range[Length[funcs]]), Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> (Row[{"Im'\[ThinSpace]", 
       HoldForm@Subscript[w, #]}] & /@ Range[Length[funcs]])]
```

[image]

You can adjust vertical `PlotRange` if needed. The main idea is to plot derivatives only when corresponding function (Re or Im of `funcs[[i]]`) is positive, that is achieved by using `UnitStep[x]` function which is 0 for `x < 0` and 1 for `x >= 0`.

Comment: Absolute lifesaver! Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I have to find the derivative of all the positive solutions now and unfortunately I am stuck again. Do you know how I could do that? so far I have 
`n = Pi/ka; 
dkdw =  D[funcs,ka];
dNdw = n/Pi * dkdw`
and then I need to plot them

Comment: Please, see my edit for plotting derivatives.